# Is there any way to move the sprites inside the sprite editor?

Tags: unity, sprites, mesh

I have imported a .png file of a stickman in which I had placed his head, body, two legs, and two hands a bit far apart from each other so that Unity will automatically convert the picture into sprites. Indeed, Unity did convert those body parts into sprites easily but now I have a problem. I made a bone going through the body and another bone going from the body to the head through the transparent area in between the sprites. Also, I have created one bone for each hand and leg and parented them to the bone in the body. The problem is that when I automatically generate geometry then the mesh rendering works completely fine within the body of the stickman, but it doesn't work anywhere else, be it the hands, or the head, or the legs. I can see the mesh only in the body of the stickman and nowhere else. Does this problem arise because the sprites are not connected, or is there any other reason? I am very new to game development, therefore please try to explain it in simple words. Thank You.
[image]

Comment: Hi welcome to gamedev exchange.can you take a screenshot from your problem?

Comment: Sure. Just a sec

Comment: If you want the mesh to connect the sprites, then they should be one piece, not separate sprites. If you want to manipulate them as separate sprites, then you should not expect the mesh to connect them. It sounds like you're getting these two different workflows crossed.

Comment: @DMGregory but my mesh isn't even appearing for the legs and hands and the head. Even if the mesh doesn't connect the sprites, shouldn't it at least appear in each sprite?

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali I have updated the question